# gethostbyname() on WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I wrote an app on WP8.
It used gethostbyname().

When I deploy app from VS2013,
This function works well.

Then I create a package from (Store Create App Packages)

Then I deploy app from (WindowsPhoneApplicationDeployment8.1)

This function can't connect to the server.

But WSAStartup() works well for both.

Did anyone has any idea why? :-P

PS:

```
When deploy from VS2013 to Emulator - Works
When deploy from VS2013 to Device   - Works
When deploy from Deploy tool to Emulator - Works
When deploy from Deploy tool to Device   - Failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally know what's going on there,

When you create a package/xap/blah,

In the Package.appxmanifest page

In the Capabilities property sub page

You must have  'internet(Client & Server)' checked.

Otherwise even ur code works properly when deploy from VS to device,

It won't work when deploy from deploy tool.

It's kind of wired, :-P